# Tomcat can't start from IDE (Eclipse Luna WTP & IntelliJ IDEA) in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am use Tomcat 8.0.12, Ubuntu 14.04.1, IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5, I try to run a simple jsp file, then IDE notice:

> Error running index.jsp (1): Error copying configuration files from
>   /opt/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/conf to
>   /home/vy/.IntelliJIdea13/system/tomcat/_EE01/conf :
>   /opt/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/conf/catalina.policy (Permission
>   denied)

I also try use Eclipse 4.4 WTP, with Tomcat 8.0.12, there are same problem, although Eclipse don't notice like IntelliJ IDEA:

> Server Error The Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v8.0
>   Server at localhost-config is missing. Check the sever for errors.
>
> Reason: The Tomcat server configuration at /Server/Tomcat v8.0 Server
>   at localhost-config is missing. Check the server for errors.

Help me resove this error.

Comment: grant permission `chmod 777 filename`, This case you may need `sudo` too

Comment: Can you figure out particular command in this situation? My **Eclipse** at: `/opt/eclipse` . **IntelliJ IDEA** at `/opt/intellij-idea` . **Tomcat server** at: `/opt/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.12` . Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow *Ruchira Gayan Ranaweera*'s comment, with:
**Eclispe** directory is: `/opt/eclipse`
**IntelliJ IDEA** directory is `/opt/intellij-idea`
**Tomcat** directory is: `/opt/tomcat8`
**Eclipse workspace** directory is default

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/eclipse -R
sudo chmod 777 /opt/intellij-idea -R
sudo chmod 777 /opt/tomcat8 -R
sudo chmod 777 /home/user_name/workspace/Servers – R
```

I have fired up the application server successfully from the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** use an installed copy of Tomcat. Use a tarball directly from Apache.

Comment: I agree with your tip, it's much much cleaner than $ chmod 777 everything

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have to open up security on all those directories (nor do most of them exist on my system).

I'm using Fedora 22 with Eclipse Luna (installed from dnf package manager) and Tomcat 8.0.23 (installed via tarball), but I imagine this would apply to other Linux distributions and versions of Tomcat.

All I needed to do was the following:

```
# chmod -R 777 /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23
```

Also, it was important to select in Eclipse under "Server Locations" the option to "Use Tomcat Installation (Takes Control of Tomcat Instatallation)" to be able to access Tomcat's home/configuration page via port 8080.

Ran Tomcat from Eclipse under servers and everything worked perfectly.

Good luck!