# tomcat not running eclipse application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I was using eclipse and tomcat 7.0 fine for all web application till yesterday but unfortunately i lost my eclipse folder(which is i am running exe) and temp folder(which is workspace directory) so i tried to add new project in new workspace(home/xx/newtemp) and tried to run by tomcat 7.0 but i am getting "**Could not clean server of obsolete files: null
java.lang.NullPointerException**".Here i show my issue by images,

[image]

Even i tried,

```
1 stop server

2 project -> clean

3 project build (I had automatic build disabled)

4 delete server

5 delete Servers folder

6 restart Eclipse
```

and also,

```
Click on Servers tab and Stop the server in use if it's running
Right click on the server again and select Clean...
Right click again and select Clean Tomcat Work Directory...
```

when i do Clean Tomcat Work Directory, getting error like below image,

and also **servers switch location in tomcat 7.0 only.**

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to delete the .snap file located in the directory :

```
<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
```

After deleting this file, you could start Eclipse with no problem.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13244429/1632286)

Comment: where is the folder i dont see it. I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It is your current working directory or workspace you chooses.

Comment: you mean eclipse workspace?if yes then there i dont see other than my project and servers.

Comment: when i open eclipse first time there asked choose workspace so i choosed home/xxx/eclipseAppHere.So you ask me to check there but here is no file name as .metadata\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71145/discussion-between-m-manivasagam-and-squiroid).

Comment: I am ready to connect with team viewer.Waiting for your reply.

Comment: I hope you can solve this bug by team viewer.So let me know when you come to online

Comment: I will come around 12:00am IST currently in office cannot help you out.

Comment: 12 am?!!! i would be in home from office so there i can not access net. Its k Mr.squiroid i try to clear myself however.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\ROOT`, and delete old existing project. %CATALINA_HOME% is your Tomcat install directory.

Comment: @M.Manivasagam http://stackoverflow.com/a/26135350/3728901 if it helpful, Let vote up :)

Comment: My problem is, server started successfully but when i add project it shows Removing obsolete files from server...
Could not clean server of obsolete files: null
java.lang.NullPointerException and that project not running.